# Nuxt.js - Vue.js SSR - performance issue - bad page speed result - big javascript script

Tags: javascript, performance, vue.js, nuxt.js, pagespeed

I'm struggling with an issue. I created an app using **Nuxt.js** [2.2.0] (https://nuxtjs.org/). Everything works perfect but page speed shows really bad results for my page.

[image]

[image]

The issue seems to be related to a number of pages and components. I deleted them for test purpose, leaving only one page, the page speed then shows about 90%. Also, this issue appears only on mobile devices, on desktop I scored 99% in this test. Are you also struggling with issue like this one? Is there any chance to do something with that?

Comment: its impossible to say anything without actual site and code. And this q would be easier solved on nuxt discord

Comment: Did you find anything helpful?